# History of technology

Tags: capacitor, components, history

Not sure this is the place for this question, but…
I have an interest in the history of very early radio technology.  There are plenty of sources on who did what when and where, but very little on what technologies (capacitors, wire etc) Marconi,for example, had available to him.  I found some Marconi schematics in a rather obscure paper, but nothing else.  Any help out there?

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't see what kind of answers you expect that would be suitable for StackExchange.

Comment: There is information available on the history of wire, capacitors etc. Once the nature of wire conductors and capacitors was understood scientists and inventors could easily employ metalsmiths, jewelers, glass blowers and other crafts people to manufacture components.

Comment: Marconi's patents are online (GB12039): https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument;jsessionid=VLqzJ38nly+f2Sd+5FhyB7hg.espacenet_levelx_prod_3?CC=GB&NR=189612039A&KC=A&FT=D&ND=&date=18970702&DB=&locale=en_EP

Comment: I recommend that you read this book: https://www.amazon.com/Much-ADO-about-Almost-Nothing/dp/0615139957, it deals with the "history of the electron" (how it was deiscovered etc.) and part of that is related to wireless communication. It will give you insight in the people involved and at what time they made their inventions. From that you can find other relevant information.

Comment: Fake...That looks like a great book.  Not sure it's exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm a small-time history buff and I just added it next to my next order.

Comment: Get Maxwell's thesis on electromagnetism. It describes all the historic research by Faraday, Coulomb, Gauss and hundreds of others that resulted in his Laws used by Marconi, Bell and others which is still used today for EM theory , design and other RF issues.

Comment: I have found Thomas H. Lee's books and articles good for history on radios and their design. He is also a pretty funny guy to listen to in lectures.

Comment: I don't see the problem; just went to Google search and typed:
"historical radio schematics" and got plenty of interesting results!
There is also a web site "http://www.radio-workshop.co.uk/index.shtml", which offers you 100's of service manuals (downloadable .pdf - files) of vintage radio receivers. Hope I've been useful, kind regards, Marco